# Weighted count of technology classes per country and per year

Tags: r, dplyr, count, weighted

I am confronted with this issue: I am trying to make a weighted count of technology classes per country and per year.
I am departing from a dataframe like this:

```
library(dplyr)  
df <- tibble(
 id = c("01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "03"), 
 year = c("1975", "1975", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1980"),
 country = c("US", "CA", "DE", "DE", "FR", "FR", "IT"),
 uspc_class = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "D"),
 fractional_count = c("0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "1"))
```

where id is the id of the patent to which the uspc_class(es) are associated and produced by one or more countries.

I want to make a count for each uspc_class to see how many are attributable to each country in each year.

I am able to make the normal count with the following code:

```
df_count <- df %>%
  group_by(uspc_class, country, year) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(cc_ijt = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

and I get the count in the cc_ijt variable in the df_count dataframe.
However, as in some cases there are multiple countries for the same id, I would like to take this into account to avoid double counting.

That is, the result I get with my code is a dataframe like this:

```
df_count <- tibble(
  uspc_class = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), 
  country = c("CA", "US", "DE", "FR", "DE",  "FR", "IT"),
  year = c("1975", "1975", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1980"),
  cc_ijt = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"))
```

What I would get is instead something like this:

```
df_count <- tibble(
  uspc_class = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), 
  country = c("CA", "US", "DE", "FR", "DE",  "FR", "IT"),
  year = c("1975", "1975", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1980"),
  cc_ijt = c("0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "1"))
```

Where cc_ijt takes into account that the count of the uspc_class has to be weighted by the fractional_count.

How can I modify my code to do this? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you could just rename `fractional_count` in your original dataframe to `cc_ijt` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of counting how many uspc_classes are attributable to each country in each year, I sum over the fractional_count column and solved the issue.

This code did it:

```
df_count <- df %>% 
group_by(uspc_class, country, year) %>%
dplyr::summarise(cc_ijt = sum(fractional_count)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = c("01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "03"), 
  year = c("1975", "1975", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1976", "1980"),
  country = c("US", "CA", "DE", "DE", "FR", "FR", "IT"),
  uspc_class = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "D"),
  fractional_count = c("0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "1"))

df %>%
  group_by(uspc_class, country, year) %>%
  mutate(fractional_count= as.numeric(fractional_count)) %>%
  summarise(n= n(),
            weighted_count= n* fractional_count)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'uspc_class', 'country'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#> # Groups:   uspc_class, country [7]
#>   uspc_class country year      n weighted_count
#>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr> <int>          <dbl>
#> 1 A          CA      1975      1            0.5
#> 2 A          US      1975      1            0.5
#> 3 B          DE      1976      1            0.5
#> 4 B          FR      1976      1            0.5
#> 5 C          DE      1976      1            0.5
#> 6 C          FR      1976      1            0.5
#> 7 D          IT      1980      1            1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This one seems to work in calculating the weighted count properly but I get then many rows and duplicates of uspc_class/country/year combination which I should not get as I am calculating the count after group_by... any idea on why it is so?

Comment: At first glance I cannot see why this would happen. Would need to see a larger dataset where this occurs to find the issue.

Comment: I did not understand why I had duplicates, but I found the solution to my problem. Instead of counting how many uspc_classes are attributable to each country in each year, I sum over the fractional_count column. This code did it: `df_count <- df %>%
  group_by(uspc_class, country, year) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(cc_ijt = sum(fractional_count)) %>%
  ungroup()`